# How to use lapply to specific indices of a list?

Tags: r, list, function, indexing, lapply

When using `lapply` to apply a function to a list, how would I do this for every other four elements in the list?

For example if i have `list` of length 100, how would I apply my function to `list[1]`, `list[5]`, `list[9]`, `list[13]` and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lapply` on the subset you're interested in.

```
> l <- as.list(1:15)
> lapply(l[seq(1,length(l),by=4)], identity)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 5

[[3]]
[1] 9

[[4]]
[1] 13
```

Or, if you want to replace the values in the original list:

```
s <- seq(1,length(l),by=4)
l[s] <- lapply(l[s], function(x) x*2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use (Using @Joshua Ulrich's data)

```
s1 <- (seq_along(l)-1)%%4+1==1
l[s1]
#  [[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 9

#[[4]]
#[1] 13
```

Or

```
s2 <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,3)) # The logical index will recycle to the length of `l`
```

It would do similar to the one below:

```
rep(s2, length.out=length(l))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[13]  TRUE FALSE FALSE


l[s2]
#  [[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 9

#[[4]]
#[1] 13
```

and then use `lapply`

Comment: You should explain why your second suggestion works, since it's probably not immediately clear to most users.

Comment: @Joshua Ulrich Thanks for the comment.  I updated with some explanation.